# How do I change two for loops to apply

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply, mapply

How do I change two `for` loops to `apply`?

```
df_trips <- data.frame(Origin=character(), 
Destination=character(), 
Trip=character(),
stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

for(i in 1:4){
  for(j in 1:4){
      Origin=i
      Destination=j
      Trip=od_matrix[i,j]
      df_temp <- data.frame(Origin,Destination,Trip)
      df_trips= rbind(df_trips,df_temp)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you properly format your question? Is there a particular reason you want to port everything to apply?

Answer (score 0):

Your whole code can be shortened to a single line:

```
cbind(expand.grid(Destination = 1:4, Origin = 1:4)[2:1], Trip = as.vector(t(od_matrix)))
```

You haven't given us `od_matrix`, so let's assume it looks like this:

```
od_matrix <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 4)
od_matrix
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    5    9   13
#> [2,]    2    6   10   14
#> [3,]    3    7   11   15
#> [4,]    4    8   12   16
```

Now:

```
cbind(expand.grid(Destination = 1:4, Origin = 1:4)[2:1], Trip = as.vector(t(od_matrix)))
#>    Origin Destination Trip
#> 1       1           1    1
#> 2       1           2    5
#> 3       1           3    9
#> 4       1           4   13
#> 5       2           1    2
#> 6       2           2    6
#> 7       2           3   10
#> 8       2           4   14
#> 9       3           1    3
#> 10      3           2    7
#> 11      3           3   11
#> 12      3           4   15
#> 13      4           1    4
#> 14      4           2    8
#> 15      4           3   12
#> 16      4           4   16
```

Which is the same result as

```
df_trips <- data.frame(Origin=character(), 
Destination=character(), 
Trip=character(),
stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

for(i in 1:4){
  for(j in 1:4){
      Origin=i
      Destination=j
      Trip=od_matrix[i,j]
      df_temp <- data.frame(Origin,Destination,Trip)
      df_trips= rbind(df_trips,df_temp)
  }
}
df_trips
#>    Origin Destination Trip
#> 1       1           1    1
#> 2       1           2    5
#> 3       1           3    9
#> 4       1           4   13
#> 5       2           1    2
#> 6       2           2    6
#> 7       2           3   10
#> 8       2           4   14
#> 9       3           1    3
#> 10      3           2    7
#> 11      3           3   11
#> 12      3           4   15
#> 13      4           1    4
#> 14      4           2    8
#> 15      4           3   12
#> 16      4           4   16
```